# How to Prevent Office365 from Butchering HTML Email Signatures

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I'm currently working on creating an HTML email signature for a client. She frequently uses both the Mac and OS X mail apps for replying to messages. I've created a custom HTML signature with her logo (as an image), and some basic contact information (h1, p, and a tags... basic stuff). A large number of her clients utilize Office365 for their businesses, and we've noticed some issues stemming from this.

It *appears* that Office365 is reformatting the code of her signature into a different XML based proprietary markup. When she receives replies from clients, her logo is blown up much larger than it should be, and certain things like links that had `text-decoration:none;` applied are now incorrectly formatted. Here's an example of what the returned raw HTML looks like from an Office365 client:

```
<h2 style=3D"mso-margin-top-alt:3.75pt;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:7.5pt;=
margin-left:0in;vertical-align:middle">
   <span style=3D"font-size:11.5pt;font-family:Geometria;color:#777777">

   </span>
</h2>
```

You'll notice every attribute has "3D" before it, and certain CSS properties have been reformatted with prefixes. Also, I used pixels for all units, but Office seems to convert to either pt or inches, which seems strange. I also see a lot of `<o:p></o:p>` tags that have been added. It generally just looks like Office365 really messes with the markup, and it causes the signature to be formatted poorly and look bad when it's sent back to her. It seems to work just fine with other clients but Office365 seems to be giving us issues.

Does anyone know of any known issues like this with other signatures, or is there any common knowledge tactic I can use to fight this undesired behavior?

Comment: The `=3D` code is a [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) escape for the equals sign.  It is converted to a pure equals sign (whose hex code is `3d`) when the HTML code is deciphered from the MIME encoding _before_ the HTML is rendered. Everything else is Microsoft's fault, though it'll render just fine (albeit perhaps slightly differently, depending on the client).  I do not think you can do anything about this, but I'm not an expert in MS tools.  That said, I recommend using `em` or `ex` for units to be relative to client's configured font sizes.

Comment: I just need to figure out a way to get things to render mainly the same. Right now, I have a left aligned logo with text to the right of it, using display:inline-block; When it gets sent to an Office365 client and back again, the logo blows up to a large size and stacks on top of the rest of the content.

Comment: ah.  you'll have to do a lot of trial and error (I can't help you as I don't have O365 or similar products).  Maybe experiment with `background-image:url(blah.png)`

Comment: if your images are bigger than the template (resized retina images) then forwarding will remove extra codes. If a full code is posted then someone can take a look at finding a solution. @adam background images dont work on Outlook as simple as that i am afraid. It uses VML.

Comment: I should have remembered that from my own experiments.  I ended up using CSS with a custom font to deliver vectorized images reliably sized and reliably attached (this has the added benefit of not getting messed up by MS's [false multipart/mixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61815 "Mozilla Bug 61815: Image not shown inline when using "cid:" due to wrong Content-Type: multipart/mixed") MIME type) ... but iirc MS clients mess that up and don't repeat it; they merely don't also attach the "image."  Lots of trial and error were needed to get even that far.

Comment: It's possible that the initial recipient using MS Outlook/Office/Office365 sees the message and signature just fine, and that it doesn't get mangled until they (the MS user) replies to you -- then only _you_ see the botched version. Have you checked that?
I'd stick with em/ex as @AdamKatz says, and I'd try to stay with styles and avoid images. I really _despise_ receiving the same image over and over from some so-and-so's email sig.

Comment: @StephenP – My font renders in MS products correctly but because it is defined in CSS that is not copied in a reply, the reply merely has colored text rather than the images in my font, thus avoiding repeated sig images (and worse, botched inline images as attachments).  That was my design.

Comment: @StephenP – That's my point. Outlook doesn't know how to copy my sig's "image" so it doesn't.  It's only when I send a message to a massive reply-all chain that it would annoy you.

Comment: @Adam - still no ... it doesn't need to be a reply or a reply-all; if I receive a single email from you every day or every other day I'm seeing that image very frequently. Now I don't know what your image is, but they are most commonly either (a) some marketing crap, or (b) a bunch of social media logos. Marketing crap I can always do without. Putting a twitter logo might tell me you're on twitter, but doesn't tell me what your twitter handle is, and if you've already mentioned your twitter handle in text then the logo is pointless. And do I really need to see our own Org's logo in every mail?

Comment: This is turning into a subjective debate that could go on for days about the importance of brand repetition for recognition, but that's not the point of my question. I'm looking for a way to have Outlook reliably handle the code I send to it in an email signature. It seems to be modifying my code and removing certain styles (like image widths). I'd like to find a way to circumvent this issue, or tell office not to mess with my code. Not sure why a parsing engine for viewing HTML tries to modify it before display anyway...